# Can we compute in polynomial time, an upper bound on an optimal solution of an integer linear program?

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, upper-bound

Consider the following integer linear program (where $A$ is an integer matrix,  $b$ an integer vector, and $c$ a positive integer vector):
$$
\text{minimize}~~~ c\cdot x
\\
\text{subject to}~~~ A\cdot x \geq b, ~~~ x\geq 0, ~~~ x~\text{is an integer vector.}
$$
Denote its optimal value by $OPT(A,b,c)$. Computing $OPT(A,b,c)$ is NP-hard in general. We are interested in computing an upper bound on $OPT(A,b,c)$, that is, a number $M = MAX(A,b,c)$ such that $OPT(A,b,c) \leq M$, and the size of $M$ (in bits) is polynomial in the size of $A,b,c$.

Is there an algorithm that, given $A,b,c$, computes such an upper bound $MAX(A,b,c)$ in time polynomial in the size of $A,b,c$?

Comment: I thought about it, but as far as I know, duality gives me a lower bound for my problem, not an upper bound. 
Maybe you have an idea how to get an upper bound for a minimization problem using duality?

Comment: What would you want such M to be if the ILP is infeasible?

Comment: @SamuelBismuth, can't you consider the relaxation of the dual of your problem? Since the dual is a maximization problem (and the optimums coincide), when you relax the constraints you are going to find an upper bound on the optimum of the original minimization problem.

Comment: @Steven The maximum of the fractional dual problem (maximization) is equal to the minimum of the fractional primal problem (minimization), which is smaller than the minimum of the integral primal problem. Therefore, it is a lower bound and not an upper bound.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi, thanks!

Comment: An upper bound is a very general request. You can for instance relax the problem, find the optimum and than take as approximate solution the nearest integer vector to the solution. This obviously gives an upper bound, with no guarantee on the quality of the solution. Maybe you need to be more specific on the kind of approximation you need. Furthermore, a solution may not exist, we have no hypothesis on $A$ other than the fact that it has integer components.

Comment: @SilvioM since it's a minimum problem, a relaxation gives a lower bound. Why would rounding to the nearest integer vector give an upper bound?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi while it is true that the optimum of a relaxation gives a lower bound, a generic admissible point gives an upper bound. Maybe I had to mention that you don't have to pick just the nearest integer vector, but rather an integer vector in the admissible space (i.e. integer vector such that $Ax\geq b$ and $x\geq 0$). The relaxation only gives you hope to be near enough to a good value, but in general every admissible vector gives an upper bound.

Comment: @SilvioM Is it always possible to find an admissible integer vector in polynomial time?

Comment: @SilvioM in LP, it is known that finding a feasible solution is as hard as finding an optimal solution. I am not sure if the same is true in ILP. In any case, it shows that finding a feasible solution is not necessarily easy.

Comment: Would you be interested in the particular case where $A$ only contains non-negative integers? That one might be solvable.

Comment: @BernardoSubercaseaux yes, this special case could be interesting.

Comment: Thanks @Erel, In such a case I think we can do more; the idea would be that you only have monotone constraints over $x$, so I think it's possible to reformulate (a relaxation) as a monotone sub-modular optimization problem. If $c$ is also non-negative, then greedily raising the components of $x$ should probably give a polynomial upper bound. The question is not trivial though, and might be better suited for the cstheory SE. If I come up with a concrete solution I will post it here!

Answer (score 0):

While The bound given by @SilvioM in comments has polynomial size in A,b,c as requested, one cannot expect a polynomial time approximation for ILPs (see the second paragraph), and hence, probably also not an an upperbound polynomial in OPT. So this is probably as good as it gets.

The reason for this is that the well-known formulation of [TSP as ILP](https://co-enzyme.fr/blog/traveling-salesman-problem-tsp-in-cplex-opl-with-miller-tucker-zemlin-mtz-formulation/) is clearly a reduction from TSP to ILP. Since the general TSP does not admit a constant factor approximation, even when all weights are inegers (try to find a gap-reduction from Hamiltonian Cycle as a homework), and since this reduction clearly preserves approximation (since any feasible solution of one of them is a feasible solution of the other having the same target value), this excludes a constant factor approximation unless P=NP.

Comment: You mentioned a constant factor approximation, but the question is about a polynomial-size upper bound.